# TypeError:null is not an object(evaluating 'RNFSManager.RNFSFileTypeRegular')

Tags: react-native, react-native-fs

I am currently working on reading a local file in react-native and am running into the following error,

`TypeError:null is not an object(evaluating 'RNFSManager.RNFSFileTypeRegular')`

The code I am using is taken straight off of the [documentation for react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs) , using the basic example, from the examples section:

```
// require the module
var RNFS = require('react-native-fs');

// get a list of files and directories in the main bundle
RNFS.readDir(RNFS.MainBundlePath) // On Android, use "RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath" (MainBundlePath is not defined)
  .then((result) => {
    console.log('GOT RESULT', result);

    // stat the first file
    return Promise.all([RNFS.stat(result[0].path), result[0].path]);
  })
  .then((statResult) => {
    if (statResult[0].isFile()) {
      // if we have a file, read it
      return RNFS.readFile(statResult[1], 'utf8');
    }

    return 'no file';
  })
  .then((contents) => {
    // log the file contents
    console.log(contents);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err.message, err.code);
  });
```

If it helps I am using vs when writing this on a Windows 10 computer.

I have tried resetting my cache, reinstalling react-native-fs, and linking react-native-fs, none have solved the problem all resulting in the same error.

I would greatly appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: have you offer write permission to the app?

Comment: I have not specifically given it permission. But i have used react-native to develop other apps and never had any issues.

Answer (score 1):

In case of iOS message is 'Native module cannot be null', In Android message is 'null is not an object evaluating RNFSManager etc'

Solution for iOS is run `pod install` in iOS Directory, then `react-native run-ios` to re-run the app.

Solution for android is `react-native link react-native-fs` then `react-native run-android` to re-run the app.